# MapView not showing - Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

I'm trying to get the map view in my app by creating it dynamically but the map view is just showing the pale yellow coloured view. I imported the MKMapView and CoreLocation frameworks. Here is my code, please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in Advance!!

```
MKMapView *map_view;
    map_view = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    map_view.showsUserLocation = YES;
    map_view.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
map_view.delegate = self;
    [_scrollView addSubview:map_view];
```

Comment: your problem is solved or not?

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD yup.. that was some problem with setting up the frame, it got fixed now. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not friendly with MkMapView, [How to use MkMapView](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Maps_on_the_iPhone_with_MapKit_and_the_MKMapView_Class)

Answer (score 0):

**in .h file you can insert following**

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
{

    IBOutlet MKMapView *mapview;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapview;
```

**in .m file you can insert following**

```
@implementation YourViewController

@synthesize mapview;

-(void)ViewDidLoad
{
    mapview.mapType=MKMapTypeStandard;
    mapview.showsUserLocation = YES;
    mapview.delegate=self;
}
```

Comment: I did it by changing the frame of the view. Thanks.. :)